# codename one uwp app app name can't chinese. name change to?

Tags: uwp, codenameone

codenameone app uwp chinese appname is ?????

I set appname is "中文"，but when install on windows 10 pc app name is ？？？？。

I want to set builder hints, change app language to Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug, I filed an issue [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1870).

Comment: FYI this was fixed and should be available tomorrow in an update